# Deactivate JS Script in Plugin Shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode, javascript, hooks, wp-enqueue-script

I am using a plugin which enqueues a javascript file in one of its shortcode functions (which I run on a page).

I don't want this file to be loaded.

So I tried using `wp_dequeue_script` in my `functions.php` file but this didn't work.

Perhaps my `functions.php` file is loaded before the shortcode that's in the page? How can I get around this issue?

The shortcode function:

```
global $dwqa, $dwqa_sript_vars, $script_version;
ob_start();

$dwqa->template->remove_all_filters( 'the_content' );

echo '<div class="dwqa-container" >';
dwqa_load_template( 'question', 'submit-form' );
echo '</div>';
$html = ob_get_contents();

$dwqa->template->restore_all_filters( 'the_content' );

ob_end_clean();
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'dwqa-submit-question', DWQA_URI . 'templates/assets/js/dwqa-submit-question.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ), $script_version, true );
wp_localize_script( 'dwqa-submit-question', 'dwqa', $dwqa_sript_vars );
return $this->sanitize_output( $html );
```

How can I not load this particular `js` file?

Comment: This is a bit of a guessing game if you don't include the code that is inserting the unwanted js file

Comment: I don't understand, the code simply calls `wp_enqueue_script`.
I will update my question, but the function is `submit_question_form_shortcode` in this file: https://github.com/designwall/dw-question-answer/blob/master/inc/Shortcode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When shortcodes are evaluated, the header of the site has already been assembled. So if the shortcode wants to [enqueue a script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) it must do so in the footer (by setting the last parameter to `wp_enqueue_script` to `true`.

At this point you're still not too late to prevent the file from actually being included in the footer. Normally, in `functions.php` you would enqueue or (de)register scripts with the `after_setup_theme` hook. However, if you look at the [order in which actions are executed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you would be trying to deregister a script long before it is enqueued.

So, you would have to find a hook that fires after the shortcode has enqueued the script. The logical choice would be `wp_footer`, like this:

```
add_action ('wp_footer','wpse240803_deregister_dwqa');
function wpse240803_deregister_dwqa() {
  wp_deregister_script ('dwqa-submit-question');
  }
```